# How to bind a Navigation-Bar "Dropdown" with asp-controllers and asp-actions . (ASP.Net Core 5 MVC)

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-5.0

Short question: I have searched the internet for an answer but I can't seem to find one that fits my situation.

This is where I want to bind some `asp-controllers` and `asp-actions`:

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="Account" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Inloggen</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Kleding bekijken</a>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Uitloggen</a>
    </div>
</li>
```

The dropdown item "Inloggen" should bind the `asp-controller` 'Account' and `asp-action` 'Inloggen'.

The dropdown item "Kleding bekijken" should bind the `asp-controller` 'Outfit' and `asp-action` 'OutfitsTonen'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like yours is the standard situation for [Anchor Tag Helpers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-6.0#anchor-tag-helper-attributes)

```
<a class="dropdown-item"
   asp-controller="Account" 
   asp-action="Inloggen">
   Inloggen
</a>
```

Comment: I know i can use this. But i don't know how to use it in my situation, how can i impliment this code inside the code i showed?

Comment: @CezarP exactly the way I wrote it. Your situation is no different, I have used this exact helper in an application of mine